# Not sure what's wrong here, no matter what I try it returns the TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, nested-lists

The assignment requires me to store the new values in a list and then update the list of lists with them. The program seems to work fine until I call 'monthly' after calling 'edit.' I'm assuming my problem is somewhere in the 'edit' function, but just in case I'm being a doof I've included the entirety of my code.

The functions and main method are in separate files

```
def Monthly(mSales):
    for row in mSales:
        print(row[0] + ' - ' + row[1])
    print()    

def Yearly(mSales):
    total = sum(int(monthlySales) for _, monthlySales in mSales)
    average = total/ len(mSales)
    print("Yearly Total:       ",total)
    print("Monthly Average:    ",round(average, 2))
    print()

def Edit(mSales):
    editMonth = input("Three-letter Month: ")
    #index = 0
    months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',
              'Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep',
              'Oct','Nov','Dec']
    if editMonth not in months:
        print("Invalid three-letter month.")
        print()
        return
    new_sales = input("Sales Amount: ")
    #index = months.index(month)
    #print(index)
    new_list = [editMonth, str(new_sales)]
    #mSales[index][1] = new_list
    for i in range(len(mSales)):
        if mSales[i][0] == editMonth:
            mSales[i] = new_list
            break
     
    print("Sales amount for {} was modified".format(editMonth))
    print()

import ch06_Monthly_Sales_commandFunctions_CJR as Func

def main():
    #initialize monthly sales list of lists
    monthlySales = [['Jan','616'],['Feb','466'],['Mar','796'], 
                    ['Apr','238'],['May','310'],['Jun','726'], 
                    ['Jul','987'],['Aug','604'],['Sep','951'], 
                    ['Oct','958'],['Nov','238'],['Dec','610']]
    print("Monthly Sales program")
    print("")
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("monthly - View monthly sales")
    print("yearly  - View yearly summary")
    print("edit    - Edit sales for a month")
    print("exit    - Exit program")
    print(" ")

    while True:
        command = input("Command: ")
        #if statements correlating to command functions
        if command == 'exit':
            print("Bye!")
            break 
        elif command == 'monthly':
            Func.Monthly(monthlySales)
        elif command == 'yearly':
            Func.Yearly(monthlySales)
        elif command == 'edit':
            monthlySales = Func.Edit(monthlySales)
        elif command != 'exit' or 'monthly' or 'yearly' or 'edit':
            print("Invalid command.")
```

Comment: It looks like you left `'May'` out of your months list in `Edit` (there are 12 months in a year, not 11).  Was that intentional?

Comment: You know the error, but which line is causing it?  It helps diagnose when the full traceback is given.

Comment: No, leaving out 'May' was certainly not intentional. Thank you for the feedback, i will include more details next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return anything from `Edit` and that `None` result gets assigned to `monthlySales`, which you pass into `Monthly()` on the next call, causing the error.

If you add `return mSales` to your `Edit()` function, your code works as expected.

Your code has some style issues as well, but that's well beyond the scope of what you're asking :).

Comment: Thank you, that was it, i feel dumb af. As for my style issues, hopefully those will get better with experience/time.

Comment: No problem, it takes courage to show your code on SO, but that's how you learn and we've all been there. If you feel the answer is sufficient, please hit the checkmark, so that it no longer shows as unanswered - and help someone else on SO some time, if you like.